# Save form with user id Django

Tags: python, django

To make my question simple I have A Form That user can upload their cv's into databse.

My forms.py

```
class resume_upload(forms.ModelForm):
    cv = forms.FileField(required = True)
    job_title = forms.CharField(required = True)

    def save(self, commit=False):
       cvs = super(resume_upload, self).save(commit=False)
       cvs.cv = self.cleaned_data['cv']
       cvs.job_title = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

       if commit:
           cvs.save()


    class Meta:
        model = Cv
        fields = ('cv', 'job_title',)
```

My models.py

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cvs', default='', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

and my views.py

```
def upload_resume(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = resume_upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.error(request,"Oops! That didn't work. Please try again")
else:
    form = resume_upload()
return render(request, 'upload_resume.html',{'form':form,})
```

And the problem is it redirect to home page but i cant find object in admin panel

Comment: Well you're never saving the objects. `commit` is always `False`.

Comment: how i can fix it

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overriding the save method like so,

```
 def save(self, commit=False):
   cvs = super(resume_upload, self).save(commit=False)
   cvs.cv = self.cleaned_data['cv']
   cvs.job_title = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

   if commit:
       cvs.save()
```

You're therefore passing a an optional parameter `commit` which is `False` by default.

You'll need to provide a `True` parameter when calling save if you want it to actually be saved.

```
form.save(commit=True)
```

**EDIT**

Also, there seems to be a problem with your code. This is probably what you intended,

```
def upload_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = resume_upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cv_form = form.save() # commit is False in this case.
            cv_form.user = request.user
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Oops! That didn't work. Please try again")
    else:
        form = resume_upload()
    return render(request, 'upload_resume.html',{'form':form,})
```

Basically here you're patching the user to the form before it is actually saved to the database. This is exactly the purpose of your boolean switch `commit`.

**EDIT 2**

To overcome your `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'` error, you would need to add this in your `save` override to return your object.

```
def save(self, commit=False):
   cvs = super(resume_upload, self).save(commit=False)
   cvs.cv = self.cleaned_data['cv']
   cvs.job_title = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

   if commit:
       cvs.save()

   return cvs
```

Comment: now there is an error NOT NULL constraint failed: app_cv.user_id

Comment: its says no migrations to apply

Comment: i get an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'